# checkbox change event firering two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm developing an app who can register for university courses. they add select their register type,course type ,batch and their subjects. i'm putting subjects on the table when they selecting a course type also the batch. So they can select subjects, after they add it will put into the selected subjects table. My code will work on when they are working @ first time. but suddenly they are changed they are register type,course type and batch it will list down the subjects. BUT when they selecting a subject it will add two table trs to the selected subjects Tables. Why is that ?

**JQUERY**

```
$("#subjectsTable").on('change', '.selectedSubjects', function (event) {
event.stopPropagation();
    var selectedReg = $('#CouserFinder option:selected').val();
    var selectedCouse = $('#CourseSet option:selected').val();
    var selectedBatch = $('#alreadyBatchSorting option:selected').val();

    if(selectedBatch != "Select Your Batch"){
    var shouldChecked = $("#CT_No_Of_SubjectsCount").val();

  var bol = $(".selectedSubjects:checkbox:checked").length >= shouldChecked;     
  $(".selectedSubjects:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var indexChecked = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
        alert(indexChecked);
        var selectedSCode = $(this).closest("tr").find(".selectedSCode").text();
        $("#selectesSubjectsRecodes tr:last").after("<tr data-index=" + indexChecked + "><td>" + selectedReg + "</td><td>" + selectedCouse + "</td><td>" + selectedSCode + "</td><td>" + selectedBatch + "</td></tr>");


    } else {
        var indexAdded = $(this).closest("tr").attr("data-index");
        var findRow = $("#selectesSubjectsRecodes tr[data-index='" + indexAdded + "']");
        findRow.remove();

    }
}
else{
alert("Warning!: Select Your Batch");
$(this).prop('checked', false)
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr class="success" data-index="10">
<td>
<input class="selectedSubjects" type="checkbox" name="selectedSubjects">
</td>
<td class="selectedSCode">BCS-DIP-UID</td>
<td class="selectedSName">UID</td>
</tr>
```

**SELECTED SUBJECT CODE (get it from the DOM )**

```
<tr data-index="10">
<td>BCS-DIP-S3</td>
<td>BCS-DIP</td>
<td>BCS-DIP-UID</td>
<td>BCS-DIP-APR/2014-002</td>
</tr>
<tr data-index="10">
<td>BCS-DIP-S3</td>
<td>BCS-DIP</td>
<td>BCS-DIP-UID</td>
<td>BCS-DIP-APR/2014-002</td>
</tr>
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

As you can see it will adding two trs.why is that ?

Comment: You should provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @Itay it's can't because those data comping from the Database

Comment: What is this line for `$(".selectedSubjects:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled",bol);`? Could it be possible that it also triggers the change event?

Comment: @Itay users can select only allowed subjects count for the course type.They can select what ever subjects we have set it via   var shouldChecked = $("#CT_No_Of_SubjectsCount").val();

Comment: Debug tip: put `console.log("fired"); return;` in the middle of your function. If there are two "fired" in the console, it means what's triggering the event again is in a row above. Then take the log and return command several rows above. When it stops writing twice to the log, you've found what's firing it again. (Assuming the onchange event doesn't just naturally being fired twice)

Comment: @Itay that change event firring two times

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VR2V8/) is working. There may be a problem either elsewhere in your javascript or with the Markup from the database. You will need to provide the markup for the table generated from the database and more javascript. Is that change event handler in a function?

Comment: @DGS yeah.this is working first time but when i selecting a register type > course type > batch again and i'll checked a subjects it will added two trs to the selected subjects table

Comment: Will need to see your complete javscript

Comment: ok wait.i'll show you

Comment: @DGS http://jsfiddle.net/pcUvu/

Comment: @Itay http://jsfiddle.net/pcUvu/

Comment: @DGS that code is a big one really

Comment: I dont see your change handler in that javascript

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36969/discussion-between-dgs-and--)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding a new event handler to `$("#subjectsTable .selectedSubjects")` every time you call that function. The problem will stem from the fact that your javascript is in a function which is being called multiple times.